# Hover div rgba with a background image without changing opacity of the text color

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need css code of mouse hover like When you hover the image it will show border color of 1px and over color opacity in rgba of the total div but without changing opacity of the text in h3 tag and before after. At the same time when hover the the text and before after color will be changed like the attached picture. I know my css code are wrong though i am putting here.
Here is the [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/h03bbys0/)

Here are the html and css code respectively---

HTML:

```
<div class="service-single-box relax-massage">
    <h3 class="service-title">Relax Massage</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.service-single-box {

    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 136px;
   }


.service-single-box:hover, .service-single-box:focus{

    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid #ab9661; 
    border-left: 1px solid #ab9661; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ab9661; 
    border-right: 2px solid #ab9661; 
    cursor: default;

   }


.service-single-box img:hover, .service-single-box img:focus{

   background-color: #282318; 
   border: 1px solid #ab9661; 
   cursor: default;
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 

   }


.relax-massage{

    background-image: url("../images/services.png");
   } 

.relax-massage h3{

   color:#fdfdfb;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 170px;
   padding-top: 20px;
  }


.relax-massage h3:hover{

   color:#a4905d; 
  }


.relax-massage h3:before {

    width: 28%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fdfdfb;
    border-top: 1px solid #fdfdfb;
    content: "";
    height: 5px;
    top: 28px;
    position: absolute;
  }
```

Comment: Please see the page design [here](http://www.shop4localdeals.com/massage/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/services.jpg)

Comment: This code works for only changing the color of text and h3 before. But it is not working when i put the hover color in rgba for entire div. Could you please have any solution for it when i hover on it rgba color will changed without changing the present hover color of text and h3 before. Only opacity working but rrgba is not working.  [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rubel01/0caj74dv/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS like this (is mostly what you did with some visualization changes and the needed changes to make it work like you want):

```
body{background:#333;}
.service-single-box {
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width:200px;
    height: 136px;

   }


.service-single-box:hover, .service-single-box:focus{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid #ab9661; 
    border-left: 1px solid #ab9661; 
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ab9661; 
    border-right: 2px solid #ab9661; 
    cursor: default;

   }


.service-single-box img:hover, .service-single-box img:focus{
   background-color: #282318; 
   border: 1px solid #ab9661; 
   cursor: default;
   background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 

   }


.relax-massage{
    background-image: url("http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/750/cache/5-week-in-space-278_75042_600x450.jpg");
    border:1px solid
   } 

.relax-massage h3{
   color:#fdfdfb;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-size: 16px;
   font-weight: bold;
   width: 170px;
   padding-top: 20px;
  }


.relax-massage h3:hover{
   color:#a4905d; 
  }


.relax-massage h3:before {

    width: 28%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fdfdfb;
    border-top: 1px solid #fdfdfb;
    content: "";
    height: 5px;
    top: 28px;
    position: absolute;
  }

.relax-massage:hover > h3:before{
   background:#a4905d; 
    border-top:none;
  }
```

You can see a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/prz8v6d9/)

**UPDATED WITH TRANSPARENCY:**

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="service-single-box relax-massage">
    <div class="overlay">
         <h3 class="service-title">Relax Massage</h3>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS code:**

```
body {
    background:#333;
}
.service-single-box {
    cursor: default;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width:200px;
    height: 136px;
}
.service-single-box:hover, .service-single-box:focus {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-top: 1px solid #ab9661;
    border-left: 1px solid #ab9661;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ab9661;
    border-right: 2px solid #ab9661;
    cursor: default;
}
.service-single-box img:hover, .service-single-box img:focus {
    background-color: #282318;
    border: 1px solid #ab9661;
    cursor: default;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.relax-massage {
    background-image: url("http://images.nationalgeographic.com/wpf/media-live/photos/000/750/cache/5-week-in-space-278_75042_600x450.jpg");
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.relax-massage h3 {
    color:#fdfdfb;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 170px;
    padding-top: 35px;
}
.overlay:hover > h3 {
    color:#a4905d;
}
.relax-massage h3:before {
    width: 28%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #fdfdfb;
    border-top: 1px solid #fdfdfb;
    content:"";
    height: 5px;
    top: 28px;
    position: absolute;
}
.overlay:hover > h3:before {
    background:#a4905d;
    border-top:none;
}
.overlay {
    background:transparent;
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    top:-15px;
}
.overlay:hover {
    background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)
}
```

Comment: Helle Fabio, Your solution works for only changing the color of text and h3 before. But it is not working when i put the hover color in rgba for entire div. Could you please have any solution for it when i hover on it rgba color will changed without changing the present hover color of text and h3 before. Only opacity working but rrgba is not working. [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/rubel01/0caj74dv/3/)

Comment: Ah, I didn't completely understand what you wanted, see http://jsfiddle.net/u64ffqn5/ for this behavior. Basically, you need to include a container box so you can style it

Comment: Hi Fabio, got the exact solution from you. Thanks for you effert. Really thanks. I have found out a solution also myself. Here is below.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another sloution------------

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rubel01/4tjeeexz/)

## HTML Code

```
  <div class="service-single-box relax-massage">
        <h3 class="holder">Relax Massage</h3>
  </div>
```

## CSS Code

```
 .service-single-box {

    margin-top: 22px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    height: 140px;
    width: auto;
 }

.service-single-box:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.2;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.holder {
    z-index: 2;
    position: relative;
}

.service-single-box:hover{
    border:1px solid #a4905d;    
} 

.service-single-box h3:before {
    width: 28%;
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    content:"";
    height: 5px;
    top: 20px;
    position: absolute; 
}
.service-single-box:hover > h3:before {
    background:#a4905d;
    border-top:none;

}
.service-single-box:hover > h3{
    color:#a4905d;
    border-top:none;
} 

.relax-massage h3 {
    color: #fdfdfb;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-top: 33px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 200px;
}
.relax-massage:before{
    background-image: url("../images/Relux massage.png");
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}  
.relax-massage:hover:before{
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    opacity: 0.08;  
    padding-top:0px;        
}
```